# HTML/Javascript - Add <div> dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I would like to dynamically add something along the lines of the following format in a new HTML page:

```
Deal Title: Deal ABC
Store Name: Store ABC

Deal Title: Deal XYZ
Store Name: Store XYZ
```

I would like `Deal Title` and `Store Name` to have the same IDs and `Deal ABC`, `Store ABC`, `Deal XYZ` and `Store XYZ` to have the same IDs so that I could refer to them and manipulate them separately in CSS.

Would someone please let me know what kind of HTML tag I should be using and what this might look like in Javascript?

I currently have this:

```
var dealTitleDiv = $('<div/>',
{   
  text:'Deal Title: ' + value.dealTitle                                                              
  ,
  id: "dealTitleDiv"
 });

var dealNameDiv = $('<div/>',
{
  text:'Name: ' + value.name                             
  ,
  id: "dealNameDiv"
});
```

However obviously, this isn't assigning tags in the way I mentioned above.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Two elements in the same page shouldn't have the same id. You should use class instead.

Comment: Thanks ejosafat, however I am still not clear on how I would separate the values and at the same time align them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add things dynamically, i recommend you to wrap everyting into a container if you haven't alredy.

```
<div id="stuff-container"></div>
```

If all your deals and stores are going to have the same style always I recommend you put the style to the class instead of the id, and just ignore the id,and with jQuery add things to the end of that container with:

```
$("#stuff-container").append(
    '<div class="deal-title">Deal Title: </div>'+ 
    '<div class="deal-item">' value.dealTitle + '</div>'
);//this will add the deal
$("#stuff-container").append(
    '<div class="store-title">Store Name: </div>'+ 
    '<div class="store-item">' value.name + '</div>'
);//this will add the store
```

I recommend you to check the documentation also http://api.jquery.com/append/
Hope this helps you.